# Idiomatic way to create, initialize and run in a single expression

Tags: rust

Sometimes you have something like this:

```
let mut something = Something::new();
something.set_property_a("foo");
something.set_property_b("bar");
let result = something.result();
```

All you ever needed was just the result, but now the scope is polluted with `something`.

In Kotlin, you can do it like that (among other versions, but using verbose one for clarity):

```
val result = Something().let { x ->
    x.propertyA = "foo"
    x.propertyB = "bar"
    x.result()
}
```

`T.let(closure)` just runs the closure giving object it was invoked on (the instance of `Something`) as the argument and returns whatever the closure returned. Extremely lightweight and easy concept, but very helpful.

Can anything similar be done in Rust? The closest I've come up with is:

```
let result = {
    let mut x = Something::new();
    x.set_property_a("foo");
    x.set_property_b("boo");
    x.result()
};
```

Comment: In both cases `x` doesn't leak into the outer scope. What else do you want?

Comment: Your example *is* what I would consider idiomatic. However, I'd normally go ahead and extract it to a function.

Comment: @JoshLee something else I'm not aware of or confirmation that this is the right way, which it seems to be, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [builder pattern](https://github.com/rust-unofficial/patterns/blob/master/patterns/builder.md). This is the idiomatic way in Rust to achieve what you want:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Something {
    property_a: String,
    property_b: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct SomethingBuilder {
    property_a: Option<String>,
    property_b: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum BuildError {
    ANotSet,
}

impl SomethingBuilder {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }

    fn with_a(mut self, a: String) -> Self {
        self.property_a = Some(a);
        self
    }

    fn with_b(mut self, b: String) -> Self {
        self.property_b = b;
        self
    }

    fn build(self) -> Result<Something, BuildError> {
        Ok(Something {
            property_a: self.property_a.ok_or(BuildError::ANotSet)?,
            property_b: self.property_b,
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let thing = SomethingBuilder::new()
        .with_a("foo".into())
        .with_b("bar".into())
        .build() // returns BuildError if set_a is left out
        .unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", thing);
}
```

See [this real world usage](http://docs.piston.rs/piston_window/glutin/struct.WindowBuilder.html) for example.

In the builder structure you can do all the verification you want when the `build` method is called. If everything is ok, you can return the newly built `struct`. The advantage of this pattern is the readability of the code (no "polluting") **and** the guarantee for the user that the built `struct` is fully valid.

Comment: Side note: I would recommend offering a Builder as part of an API, for completeness, however if in my program I only "needed" a Builder once or twice, I'd just use Block Expressions.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sure, that is an overkill for a one or two times usage (~30 lines instead of 4)